# How to "import" CDN libraries or non-CommonJS libraries in ES2015/babel?

Tags: requirejs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Former I coded html5 project using AMD + require.js.
In this environment, if I want to load remote libraries on cdn or to load non-AMD libraries, add them to config.js and use paths/shim attributes.
Like

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        "jquery" : "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min",
        "jui" : "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery' : {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'jui' : { 
            deps: ['jquery'] 
        }
    }
});
```

Now I try to switch using Babel(ES2015) + webpack + gulp.
I understand how to load CommonJS libraries in local server, but how can I use non-CommonJS libraries or libraries in remote CDN at this environment?

Comment: With webpack you can either include jQuery/JUI via a `<script>` tag and use the [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) property, or use [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) to pull the dependency in at runtime